# Auto fade/show between multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's a simple jQuery script I can load on my webpage that will auto fade between each of the three "box" divs, and repeat? I'd like it to show a div for 5 seconds while hiding the other two, then run a 1 second fade transition into the next.

The three div's are currently stacked on top of each other.

```
<div class="boxes">

<div class="box1">text1</div>
<div class="box2">text2</div>
<div class="box3">text3</div>

</div>
```

Comment: The key is using the the style attributes of `position`, `z-index`, `display` and a `setInterval` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var allBoxes = $("div.boxes").children("div");
    transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox(from, to) {
    function next() {
        var nextTo;
        if (to.is(":last-child")) {
            nextTo = to.closest(".boxes").children("div").first();
        } else {
            nextTo = to.next();
        }
        to.fadeIn(500, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                transitionBox(to, nextTo);
            }, 5000);
        });
    }

    if (from) {
        from.fadeOut(500, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CYJLA/

I'm sure it could be cleaned up and/or be more efficient, but I just put it together to get it working.

Comment: This is almost perfect! :) However, it seems to wait 15 seconds for the first transition to happen, and then 5 seconds each transition after that. I wonder what's giving it that extra 10 seconds at the start. hmmmmm.

Comment: @copyflake Thanks! Hmm well I didn't/don't see that happening. Are you seeing that happen in the fiddle? For me, it immediately fades in the first one, then 5 seconds later fades in the next, 5 seconds later fades in the next, then 5 seconds later starts over.

Comment: you're right. It must be something on my end, the jsfiddle is working fine! I will play around with it :) Thank you so much.

Comment: @copyflake Haha alright, well let me know if you need more help integrating it. No problem though :)

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is easy to set-up and can do what you are asking.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/4PvU7/

```
$('.boxes').cycle({
    speed: 1000, // speed of the transition
    timeout: 5000 // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance) 
});
```

Comment: I think that plugin looks for the `img` tag inside the target div and cycles it. I don't think the OP is in a position to modify it to suit his/her needs.

Comment: It doesn't just cycle images, as stated in the introduction: `Each child element of the container becomes a "slide".` Please see my example.

Comment: Oh ok. Nevermind. I used to use it a lot and in those days it used to work like I mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Bouillou/UQTY2/52/

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="fade-effect box1">text1</div>
    <div class="fade-effect box2">text2</div>
    <div class="fade-effect box3">text3</div>
</div>

jQuery.fn.nextOrFirst = function (selector) {
    var next = this.next(selector);
    return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.fade-effect').fadeOut(500);

    var fadeInTime = 1000;
    var intervaltime = 5000;

    //First call
    setTimeout(function () {
        fadeMe($('div.fade-effect').first());
    }, intervaltime);

    function fadeMe(div) {
        div.fadeIn(fadeInTime, function () {
            div.fadeOut(fadeInTime);

            //Recursive call
            setTimeout(function () {
                fadeMe(div.nextOrFirst());
            }, intervaltime);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box2,.box3").css("display","none");
    var a=2;
    function recursive()
    {

    $(".box1,.box2,.box3").css("display","none");  
    $(".box"+a).fadeIn(1000);

    a=Number(a)+1; 
    if(a==4)
    a=1;
    }

    setInterval(function(){recursive()},5000);

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="boxes">

    <div class="box1" c>text1</div>
    <div class="box2">text2</div>
    <div class="box3">text3</div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: when I try this one, it initially shows box1, but then after 5 seconds, everything disappears, and the second and third boxes don't appear. Just blank.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one of the simplest solution:

**CSS:**

```
.boxes { position:relative; height:332px; width:500px; }
.boxes div { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.boxes div:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
    $('.boxes :first-child').fadeOut().next('div').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.boxes');
}, 3000);
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qaUtC/)**</kbd>