# Looping fade between two divs - require modification to answer to this post

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, fade

The accepted answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893913/auto-fade-show-between-multiple-divs) is exactly what I need, *but* with one modification.

I need multiple `.boxes`. Not just one.

Each "box" has two divs that need to be faded between.

From this snippet of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var allBoxes = $("span.boxes").children("span");
    transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});
```

I understand that I should maybe first, put all the `.boxes` into an array and then loop over that to get each of their children `span` elements.

But I'm not entirely sure that this is (a) the best practice, (b) correct, and (c) if there is just a better way in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/8odoros/CYJLA/306/ ?

Using

```
$( "div.boxes" ).each(function( index ) {
  var allBoxes = $(this).children("div");
  transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});
```

applies the same effect to all `.boxes`

Comment: YES! A thousand time yes. Thank you so much. I knew it would be a one-liner. Thank you.